# How to read data from .conf file using python?

Tags: python

I have a sample file: `sample.conf`

```
read{

  host => "localhost"

  port => "8080"

}
```

How do I read the data from the `config` file using python?

Is there any module in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you writing conf file in json format

Comment: what kind of config you wote is ?

Comment: It just read the data jia Jimmy ..For example if  i need to connect mysql then it read its host,username and password,database name from the .conf file

Answer (score 1):

If the standard `.ini` format can be followed in your config file,

```
[read]
host => "localhost"
port => "8080"
```

Then use `configparser` library.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
data_file = 'sample.conf'

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(data_file)

print(config.sections())

print(config['read']['host'])
```

Output

```
['read']
> "localhost"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But i need to read .conf for further process Sleeba paul .Do you have any idea regarding that?

Comment: Do you have control over the way the `conf` file is? Or you can't change it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Sleepa.. section read is of list datatype .what about the type of variables host and port?? Do they also belongs to list ??Can you please clarify me

Comment: You write a standard `.ini` file with the format I mentioned in the answer. `[read]` is not list dtype but the usually an env variable. Say, database variables like database URL comes under [database] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

honestly it depends on what you mean by "read the file" if you are talking about reading it like any other text file just use something like

```py
with open("example.conf", 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Output

```
hello world
```

the code above reads the file as a text file
however if you want to read it as a .conf file do something like this

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
data_file = 'sample.conf'

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(data_file)

print(config.sections())

print(config['read']['host'])
```

Output

```
['read']
> "localhost"
```